# Recursion under a heap class

Tags: java, arrays, heap

I am trying to solve the following problem.

"Define a recursive method named inOrderTraverse under the Heap class to perform inorder
traversal over the nodes in the heap."

In the above problem, Do I convert the heap array to BST to run In order Traversal or Can I perform In order traversal over a heap array using recursion? if so How? Any other different insights on the problem will also be helpful.

If you want to check the whole code,
https://github.com/iaminhri/DSATheoriesAndCodes/blob/main/src/Heap.java

I am only facing on the following section where I have to traverse a heap using In Order Traversal using recursion.

```
public class Heap extends HeapSkeleton<Integer>{
    
public boolean isLeaf(int pos){
    return pos > currentSize/2;
}

public void inOrderTraversal(int pos){
    if(isLeaf(pos))
        return;
    else{
        inOrderTraversal(2 * pos);
        System.out.print(heapArr[2*pos] + " " );
        inOrderTraversal(2 * pos + 1);
    }
}
}
```

//Main Class

```
public class DSAClassDriverList {
    public DSAClassDriverList(){
        Heap newHeap = new Heap(10);
        newHeap.insert(5);
        newHeap.insert(10);
        newHeap.insert(20);
        newHeap.insert(3);
        newHeap.insert(13);
        newHeap.insert(7);

        newHeap.printHeap();

        System.out.print("In Order Sort: ");
        newHeap.inOrderTraversal(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new DSAClassDriverList(); }
}
```

//The following output of the program which is not correct in terms of In order traversal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function is printing `heapArr[2*pos]`, which evidently means it can only ever print data at **even** indices.

Instead the function should have as goal to print the value of the *given* `pos` and of its subtrees.

This also means you need to change the stop condition: it should just verify that `pos` is a *valid* index (in range).

So:

```
public void inOrderTraversal(int pos){
    if (pos > currentSize) {
        return;
    } else {
        inOrderTraversal(2 * pos);
        System.out.print(heapArr[pos] + " " );
        inOrderTraversal(2 * pos + 1);
    }
}
```